# C# Mongo retrieve sub document

Tags: c#, mongodb

I has the following documents in my collection:

```
{
    "Target_Year" : 2017,
    "Target_Month" : 6,
    "Performance" : [ 
       {
        "Report_Day": 1,
        "First_Level_Superior" : "WS66",
        "Second_Level_Superior" : "SB23"
    }, 
    {
        "Report_Day": 2,
        "First_Level_Superior" : "CN4",
        "Second_Level_Superior" : "WS66"
    }, 
    {
        "Report_Day": 3,
        "First_Level_Superior" : "",
        "Second_Level_Superior" : "TN27"
    }]
}
```

The following is my current filtering codes:

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filterMain = builder.Eq("Target_Year", "2017") & builder.Eq("Target_Month", "6") & builder.Eq("Performance.Report_Day", "1");
var result = mongoDB.Performance.Find(filterMain).FirstOrDefault();
```

What I need to retrieve actually is just:

```
    {
        "Report_Day": 1,
        "First_Level_Superior" : "WS66",
        "Second_Level_Superior" : "SB23"
    }
```

OR

```
 {
    "Target_Year" : 2017,
    "Target_Month" : 6,
    "Performance" : [ { 
        "Report_Day": 1,
        "First_Level_Superior" : "WS66",
        "Second_Level_Superior" : "SB23"
    }]
}
```

Any help is really greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a ["projection"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#projection) with the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) to reference the matched array item from the query conditions:

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filterMain = builder.Eq("Target_Year", "2017") & builder.Eq("Target_Month", "6") &
    builder.Eq("Performance.Report_Day", "1");
var project = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("Performance.$");

var result = mongoDB.Performance.Find(filterMain).Project(project).FirstOrDefault();
```

The `$` represents the "index" of the array which was matched in the query expression with:

```
builder.Eq("Performance.Report_Day", "1");
```

Comment: @CheeMun Good. With your newly gained [reputation privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) you can vote up as well :)